# good readiness probe for zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I've noticed that all examples of k8s readiness probes rely on "ruok" command.
But what i observe - zookeeper replies "imok" even if it cannot serve requests. If disk is full, for example - it replies "imok" cause process is alive, but all other commands are rejected with "zookeeper doesn't serve requests". with this i add "srvr" command to readiness probe.

Question is - can it be harmful? I need 100% reliable ensemble :)
Should i add "srvr" to liveness probe as well, are there any side-effects?